# HMAC SHA256 calculation [different values generated]

Tags: java, digital-signature, hmac

I have a function that is responsible for calculating a hash value using `HmacSHA256` algorithm on providing it a payload. The final output generated by this function doesn't match the output of calculated here (https://www.javainuse.com/hmac)

My function looks like the following

```
    public String generateHmacKey (String sftpResponseObj){
        log.warn("SFTP response: (" + sftpResponseObj + ")");
        String encodingType = "HmacSHA256";
        String hash = "";
        try{
            //Get an algorithm 
            Mac sha256Mac = Mac.getInstance(encodingType);
            // Create secret key
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(this.secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), encodingType);
            log.warn("Secret key: (" + secretKeySpec + ")");
            
            //Assign secret key
            sha256Mac.init(secretKeySpec);
            //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(sftpResponseObj);
            //log.warn("Stringified SFTP response: (" + obj + ")");
            

            // Generate Base64 encoded string
            Base64 base64 = new Base64();
            hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256Mac.doFinal(sftpResponseObj.getBytes("UTF-8")));

            log.warn("Output: (" + hash + ")");

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InvalidKeyException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return hash;
    }
```

The output of the above hash is `59CqKqY8sXfc1L2lauqh6QYDmp83USyGpbpJgrOQBuo=`

The secret key i am passing to the function is `ZzVhq3sQkjdRsEy`

The **sftpResponseObj** in the above function is as following

```
{"id":"ffafb7a3-1701-496f-b5b5-390ad5b7f954","success":"1","comment":"\nWarning#: 20965 Msg: WARNING - RR CODE NOT SET UP FOR EXT - SYSTEM HAS CHANGED EXT TO Panel: AP.KU Info: CLIENT ID 6CH4D8    \nAccount 6CH4D8S opened successfully.\nAccount 6CH4D8W opened successfully.\n","client_id":"6CH4D8"}
```

Upon verifying with the online tool(https://www.javainuse.com/hmac) i get a different output, please see the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: When I run your code with the input string you give above, I get the same hash as you get with https://www.javainuse.com/hmac. You must be using a different value for `sftpResponseObj`.

Comment: I get `3oINkYngevZJn3rTkIzxcwd5/dU5t2PYb3nffyZbBMU=` via the tool but different via the code. Just tried again :(

Comment: Use a static string for `sftpResponseObj`.